# How to make a StringVar update its value when changing in tkinter?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from math import *
from turtle import delay
from pylab import *
import time

my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("200x500")  # Size of the window 
my_w.title("Puls")  # Adding a title

sv = StringVar() #string variable 
sb = Spinbox(my_w,textvariable=sv, width=15,from_=0,to=100)
sb.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=50,pady=10)

sc = Scale(my_w, from_=0, to=100,orient=HORIZONTAL,variable=sv)
sc.grid(row=2,column=1,padx=50)

def f(x): 
    return 0.45*x**3-8*x**2+52*x+66

x = float(sv.get())
y = f(x)

label = tk.Label(
    text=y,
    height=5
)

label.grid(row=3,column=1,padx=50)

label2 = tk.Label(
    text=x,
    height=5
)

label2.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=50)

my_w.mainloop()  # Keep the window open
```

I need to make the variable to change so my function actually works. How would I do this? Right now I think the code will work, but the variable `x` which is determined by a `StringVar` is only valued at one point the start.

Comment: General `tkinter` thought process: *When do you want the function to get called?* If it's just once, ahead of time, then why not just do it *before creating the UI*, so that you know the final value to use for the text? Otherwise, it presumably happens *in response to some kind of event*, in which case you can just set the value in the callback (along with the actual function logic). In your case, it appears that the event you have in mind is "changing the value represented in the `StringVar`" - yes, `trace_add` is used to get an event for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sv.trace_add(...)` to execute a function whenever the value of `sv` is changed:

```py
...

# used to show the result of f(x)
label = tk.Label(height=5)
label.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=50)

# used textvariable=sv to show the 'x' value
label2 = tk.Label(textvariable=sv, height=5)
label2.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=50)

def on_change(*args):
    x = float(sv.get())
    y = round(f(x), 2)  # change 2 to whatever value you want
    label.config(text=y)

sv.trace_add('write', on_change) # call on_change() whenever sv is changed
on_change() # show initial result

my_w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `sv.get()` at the time you do the calculation, not before.

```
def do_func():
    x = float(sv.get())
    y = f(x)
    label.configure(text=y)
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but it leaves open the question of getting `do_func` to be called at appropriate times. From the context in OP's code, it seems that this should happen whenever the value in the underlying `StringVar` changes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: you weren’t very clear about when you want the function to be called. Doy you want it to be called whenever the scale is moved?